# Is sound wave detection distance related to modulation algorithm?

Tags: signal-detection

Recently I have read [this paper](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/7218629/).

The author claimed that the audio signal detection (communication using sound signal) distance was affected by audio signal modulation method, by optimizing the audio signal's modulation algorithm, communication range between devices can be largely increased.

However, I think that the audio propagation media properties, audio receiver's performance really matter.Can somebody help me with this issue?
Thank you very much

Comment: Why one or the other? Can’t they both matter?

Comment: Let me clarify my question, if the hardware of the audio receiver or the media physical properties remains unchanged, can audio signal's modulation algorithm really improve the detection distance?

Comment: There are some simple examples, if you send a tone, doubling the duration of the tone, should provide a 3dB gain, the distance increases, but the data rate is approximately halved.

Comment: Thank you, so where on the internet I can refer to these examples' documents? I do not understand where does the 3dB gain come from?

Comment: It’s the gain of a matched filter when the integration time increases. If you are reading IEEE papers, a basic understanding of detection theory helps. I’ll post a reference as an answer

Comment: Thank you, now my idea is that first, the audio receiver (mic) should be sensitive enough to generate an output signal from the very weak acoustic stimulus, then, by optimizing the algorithm, the audio receiver can detect the incoming audio signal more easily, is that correct?

Comment: Yes that is the basic idea. Picture a 60 year old man who listens to Led Zeppelin very loud next to a 16 year old violin prodigy. Who will hear the farthest?